# Issues with mmap of Complex Types

Tags: c, memory, shared, mmap

I have an issue attempting to access shared memory using mmap for complex types.

So I allocate my memory as so in my parent process:

```
/* Create mmap file */
fid = open(TMP_FILE_NAME, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_EXCL, (mode_t) 0755);
if (fid < 0)
{
  printf("Bad Open of mmap file <%s>\n", TMP_FILE_NAME);
  die(-1);
}

/* Make mmap file Buffer Size */
status = ftruncate(fid, INPUT_BUFFER_SIZE); 
if (status)
{
    printf("Failed to ftruncate the file <%s>, status = %d\n", TMP_FILE_NAME, status);
    die(-1);
}

/* Initialize Shared Memory */
mmap_ptr = mmap((caddr_t) 0,
      INPUT_BUFFER_SIZE,        // Default Buffer Size
      PROT_WRITE | PROT_READ,   // R/W Permissions
      MAP_SHARED, // No file backing
      fid,  
      (off_t) 0);
if (mmap_ptr == MAP_FAILED)
{
    printf("Failed to perform mmap, Exiting\n");
    die(-1);
}
```

Now the Struct that I'm passing in memory to my child process is as follows:

```
/* Data structue for IPC */
typedef struct {
    int current_active_id;
    int consume_remaining;
    Queue buffer;
} input_buffer;
```

where Queue is a data structure class from the following:
http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Programming/data_structures/c/Queue/Queue.shtml

In my child process it's okay when I do this, it returns the correct value:

```
printf("Got here... Shared Mem: %d\n", input_queue->consume_remaining);
```

but when I do something like:

```
IsEmpty(input_queue->buffer)
```

it crashes and in the code of the Queue it's only doing this:

```
return Q->Size == 0;
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: input_queue->buffer is not a valid memory address in the child process. How are you doing IPC here? You need to mmap the same 'shared' file in the child process to perform IPC.

Comment: I basically start the child process and create another mmap_ptr and cast it to the input_queue type. This works fine for basic types of int, but not the pointer to the Queue. How would I go about allocating the queue data structure to be part of the shared mem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Queue` is a pointer to `struct QueueRecord`, and should be allocated as such, presumably using the same shared memory segment. note that this should also be mapped at the same address in both parent and child, or you will not be able to dereference it.

Comment: Okay, I see that makes sense. So in http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Programming/data_structures/c/Queue/queue.c instead of the malloc, I would do an mmap?

Comment: Or to be more clear, how would I malloc it in to the same address area as the struct I mmap'ed?

Comment: @JKao: You could change the code so your mapped area contains a `struct QueueRecord`, which may be modified to have a flexible member for use as the array, instead of using an allocated pointer. note though that the current implementation hides the definition of the struct.

Answer (score 1):

The structure you are putting in the map contains pointers. The pointers are all relative to the address space of the process that created them.

If the other process doesn't mmap at the same address, or if it does but the allocations made for the queue aren't taken from inside that buffer, the pointers will be invalid in the other process.